# Не отрабатывает метод onWebhookUpdateReceived() в телеграм боте

Tags: java, telegram-bot, spring-boot

Проблема проста - при отправлении сообщения боту через телеграм, я ожидаю, что метод `onWebhookUpdateReceived(Update update)` будет срабатывать на подобие метода `onUpdateReceived(Update update)` который есть при наследовании от `TelegramLongPollingBot`, но у меня это не происходит.

Подробности - есть телеграм бот который должен работать на `Webhooks` написанный с помощью библиотеки

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.telegram</groupId>
   <artifactId>telegrambots-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
   <version>6.7.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Есть временный сервис для тестирования `webhooks` - https://webhook.site/
После написания конфигов когда я отправляю любое сообщение сервис https://webhook.site/ ловит http запрос, т.е. коннект есть, тут все хорошо. Но если я правильно понимаю, в это же время, у меня должен срабатывать метод `onWebhookUpdateReceived(Update update)`, но он не работает. Проверяю обычным выводом в консоль.

pom файл

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>JiraNotifications</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>JiraNotifications</name>
    <description>JiraNotifications</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-redis</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-redis</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.telegram/telegrambots-spring-boot-starter -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.telegram</groupId>
            <artifactId>telegrambots-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>6.7.0</version>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Главный класс с наследованием от `SpringWebhookBot` - TelegramApp

```
import lombok.AccessLevel;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;
import lombok.experimental.FieldDefaults;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.api.methods.BotApiMethod;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.api.methods.send.SendMessage;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.api.methods.updates.SetWebhook;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.api.objects.Update;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.starter.SpringWebhookBot;

import java.io.IOException;

@Getter
@Setter
@FieldDefaults(level = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
public class TelegramApp extends SpringWebhookBot {
    String webHookPath;
    String botUserName;
    String botToken;

    public TelegramApp(SetWebhook setWebhook, String botToken) {
        super(setWebhook, botToken);
    }

    @Override
    public BotApiMethod<?> onWebhookUpdateReceived(Update update) {
        System.out.println("check onWebhookUpdateReceived");
        if (update.hasMessage() && update.getMessage().hasText()) {
            SendMessage sendMessage = new SendMessage();
            sendMessage.setChatId(update.getMessage().getChatId().toString());
            sendMessage.setText("Well, all information looks like noise you break the code.");
            return sendMessage;
        }
        return null;
    }

    private BotApiMethod<?> handleUpdate(Update update) throws IOException {
        System.out.println(" check handleUpdate");

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String getBotUsername() {
        return botUserName;
    }

    @Override
    public void onRegister() {
        super.onRegister();
    }

    @Override
    public String getBotPath() {
        return webHookPath;
    }
}
```

класс контроллер - WebhookController

```
import com.zherikhov.jiranotifications.TelegramApp;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.api.methods.BotApiMethod;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.api.objects.Update;

@RestController
@AllArgsConstructor
public class WebhookController {
    private final TelegramApp telegramApp;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public BotApiMethod<?> onUpdateReceived(@RequestBody Update update) {
        return telegramApp.onWebhookUpdateReceived(update);
    }
}
```

Класс с запуском приложения `JiraNotificationsApplication`

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class JiraNotificationsApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(JiraNotificationsApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Так же есть еще 2 класса с конфигами: BotConfig и SpringConfig, но так как на этой стороне логика работает корректно, наверное прикладывать большого смысла нет что бы не захламлять.